# Tika could not delete temporary files

Tags: java, io, garbage-collection, apache-tika, memory-mapping

In our application we are processing files using Apache Tika. But there are some files (e.g. *.mov, *.mp4) which Tika cannot process and leaves the corresponding *.tmp file in the user's Temp folder. After some research I found that it is a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1040?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

In the last comment a user talks about a workaround but it does not work for me:

```
final Tika tika = new Tika();
final TikaInputStream fileStream = TikaInputStream.get(/*some InputStream*/);
try {
    final String extractedString = tika.parseToString(fileStream);
    //do something with the string
} finally {
    CloseUtils.close(fileStream);
}
```

Using the code above still leaves temp files in the Temp folder. What could be a solution to this?

Comment: If you're on Linux/Unix, you could let a cronjob clean up the temporary files.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Windows and I also have to solve this from Java.

Comment: Well, on Windows you could use the Task Scheduler, but not if you have to solve this from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get() method should be called with a File object instead of an InputStream:

```
final File file = new File("c:/some_file.mov");
final TikaInputStream fileStream = TikaInputStream.get(file);
```

Tika still cannot process it but it actually manages to delete the correspondig tmp file.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is disabling the `org.apache.tika.parser.mp4.MP4Parser`. Two solutions are here:

- [with configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597077/843804)
- [with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416836/843804)